# Understanding voltage in simple electromagnet and DC motors

Tags: dc-motor, inductor, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

I made a simple electromagnet with enameled copper wire wrapped many times around a metal allen wrench. I attached the electromagnet to my PSU and it works great, but I do not understand the voltage output.

I understand that the magnetic flux is proportional to the ampere turns; more turns more current, more magnetism. The voltage does not go above 1.5 V regardless of the PSU setting (30 V/5 A) and draws the maximum current at 5 A; so I get roughly 7.5 W.

This amount of copper will roughly be the same for a single phase slot of a reluctance motor (high/low sides) design; about 6-8 feet of 20 AWG wire. I will be using a circuit to drive the motor with max 24 V and 5 A.

**How can I increase the voltage across the inductor to achieve higher current? Thinner gauge wire and a significant amount of more turns for more resistance?**

I am comparing this electromagnet to what will be the inductor in the stator (laminated) and it is not the ideal power. I thought the voltage would be that of the PSU setting for the electromagnet, then translate that to the stator slot to determine performance. Ideally a single phase can achieve 24 V 2-3 A.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the DC resistance of the coil you created? That will tell you the maximum current it will draw at a certain voltage. Your PSU may not be capable of supplying the total current needed by the coil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I increase the voltage across the inductor to achieve higher current? Thinner gauge wire and a significant amount of more turns for more resistance?

Yes, that's one way.

Not accounting for poor connections, your existing coil has a resistance of

$$ R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{1.5V}{5A} = 0.3\Omega $$

In practice it will be less than this, because I imagine there's also some resistance in the interconnections and wiring between coil and supply.

If you wish to use this power supply, limited to 30V & 5A, you require a resistance which will pass exactly 5A when 30V is across it:

$$ R = \frac{30V}{5A} = 6\Omega $$

That's a factor of 20 times larger than the existing resistance, so you'll either need 20 times longer wire, or the same length of wire with \$\frac{1}{20}\$ of the cross sectional area.

---

Your PSU will output *no more than* 5A, and if the load tries to draw more than that, the PSU will simply drop its output voltage to whatever voltage is necessary across the load, to draw 5A.

As for the motor, if it has similar coil resistance, then initially it will cause the same 28.5V drop in PSU output, for the same reasons.

If that voltage/current is enough to cause the motor to start turning, then slowly it will accelerate, leaving the stall condition, requiring less and less current to run.

As it turns faster, the load it presents to the PSU falls. PSU output voltage can rise, and eventually motor current will reach a minimum (presumably less than 5A, with the motor unloaded), and then the PSU is able to output its "set" voltage.

Comment: Excellent. This is a really great explanation and will help me with baseline performance predictions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase the voltage is to increase the rate of change of current, or increase the inductance (add more turns, increase relative permeability of the core material), or both. "voltage across an inductor" in steady-state DC conditions is parasitic loss and will do no work.

Another way to look at your question, is how do you drive more current through the inductor to get more power out of the power supply. To do that you need a chopper. Either a half bridge of two switches, or a bridge and a diode. The chopper can also limit the field current, which will provide speed control.

Note that when the motor is spinning, the voltage it develops will be higher, this is due to the changing magnetic field from the rotor inducing back-EMF into the stator. You are currently simulating a stalled or starting condition.